# Put a number of spheres in an animation with the same distance

Tags: javascript, animation, async.js, tween.js

I have a code that performs animation. a sphere moves from the beginning of a line to the end of the line. When starts again ends the motion again. starts from the first vertex and ends at the last vertex of the line.
I want to put 20 or so spheres, doing the same animation, but at the same time and in the same distance.
How can I do it?

this is my code:

```
var vertices = mesh.geometry.vertices;
var duration = 10;

function startToEnd() {
    var i = 0;
    async.eachSeries(vertices, function(vertice, callback) {
        if (i !== 0) {
            sphere.position.copy(vertices[i - 1]);
            new TWEEN.Tween(sphere.position).to(vertices[i],  duration).delay(duration).onComplete(function() {
                callback(null);
            }).start();
        } else {
            callback(null);
        }
        i++;
    }, startToEnd);
}
startToEnd();
```

this image is a example..
[image]

this is result of my code
[image]

Comment: what you are looking for is `Arc Length of a Curve`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got something that I think is pretty close to what you want:

```
var vertices = mesh.geometry.vertices;
var duration = 20;
var spheres = [];
var amountOfSpheres = 20;

for (var i = 0; i < amountOfSpheres; i++) {
  spheres.push(new THREE.Sprite(rttMaterial));
  scene.add(spheres[i]);
}

function endlessArrayIndex(index, arrayLength) {
    if (index >= arrayLength) {
    return index % arrayLength;
  }
  return index;
}

function startToEnd() {
  i = 0;
  async.each(spheres, function(sphere, cb1) {
    var j = 0;
    var verticeIndex = endlessArrayIndex(i * Math.round(vertices.length / amountOfSpheres), vertices.length);
    async.eachSeries(vertices, function(vertice, cb2) {
      if (verticeIndex !== 0) {
        var verticeToCopy = vertices[verticeIndex - 1];
        sphere.position.copy(verticeToCopy);
        new TWEEN.Tween(sphere.position).to(vertices[verticeIndex], duration).delay(duration).onComplete(function() {
          cb2(null);
        }).start();
      } else {
        cb2(null);
      }
      verticeIndex = endlessArrayIndex(verticeIndex + 1, vertices.length);
    }, cb1);
    i++;
  }, startToEnd);
}
startToEnd();
```

Result of the above code:

[image: Sphere movement result from the code above]

Comment: friend, thank you're a genius. in theory it works as I want. the only problem is that the distance between each sphere is not the same. What should be done to fix it?

Comment: @yavg I updated my answer with a better way of calculating distance between spheres.

Comment: excellent, you're the smartest person I've seen in this community, and maybe in my life !. Thank you!